# MS Excel to HTML gridlines missing in Google Chrome

Tags: html, excel

I'm trying to convert from excel spreadsheet (.xls) to html via MS Excel 2010, but I'm wanting to keep the gridlines.  So I'm highlighting all cells -> format cells -> outline and inside border presets, normal border, black color, and then doing the export.  Viewed with IE and Firefox, the borders are there.  However, when viewed with chrome, the borders are gone and I instead see style="border-left: none;" inside of each td tag.

The purpose of this is to make an excel spreadsheet preview for a webpage, and it's looking like the export-to-html route is probably the easiest.  Does anyone know of a better route?

I'm thinking my only solution may be to just have javascript check specifically for chrome and edit the border left/right/top/bottom styles on all the td tags.  Is there something I'm missing?

---

Also, is there a way to keep the row numbers and column letter headers in the html version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a find/replace for all the instances where the source code reads `border-left:none`, `border:none`, etc... then use css styles to make sure the gridlines stay with the data. Assuming it is exported as a table, use

```
<style type="text/css">
    table{
       border: 2px solid #000000;
    }
    td{
       border: 1px solid #000000;
    }
</style>
```

(format to your own taste and liking)

As for the row numbers and column headers, it depends how much data you have. If there's not much, it would be easiest to hand-type in the headings and numbers. If it's a lot, the best way would be to use javascript or a server-side language to print out the row headings for you.

Comment: Using chrome's dev tools, I found that style to work for the table elements but not for the td elements.  The td elements have class="xl165" class names on them, which when removed allow for the td borders to show (except for the inline border-left section, which then also has to be removed from the inline style attribute).

In short, via javascript, one could inject your styles into the inline style sheet that's already there, then remove that class name and inline border style from each td tag.  Would need onclick set on all the tabs in the worksheet frame to call this code.

Comment: or you could modify the `xl165` class yourself, and just use the name they gave all those cells and style it your own way in the css ... it might be a little less messy that way

Comment: That'd be a much more efficient solution if it weren't for the individual inline border styles on each td tag.  
------
I just realized I could probably just do a string replace for "border*:none" to "border: 1px solid #000" on the server for each worksheet page after I generate the spreadsheet and export it to html.  While I'm messing with it via python or whatever, I may as well count the number of tr tags, and then find the largest number of td tags within a single tr tag, and generate the line numbers and column headers from there.  Basically base 10 to base 26 for the headers.

Comment: sounds like a good plan. I didn't know what weapons were at your disposal, but if you're in python, definitely go with that for the line numbers. Alternatively, if you're familiar with jQuery, it would be fairly painless to append a <td> after each <tr> with an iteration number.  

I guess I didn't explicitly say to delete those inline border styles. That's probably a good thing to do anyway for cleanliness of your markup and your own sanity in the long run!

Answer (score 3):

a very lazy fix is to select the bigger size border line in excel before saving as a webpage. It was bugging me a while ago and it's the fix I found and I used it since then, I maintained a hockey pool exporting daily teams stats & standings in tables and it render just fine in chrome using this trick.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is to access your google drive, import your xls file, and then download it as an html file. The generated web page works perfectly in both Chrome and IE.